# how to check if IIS or ASP.NET worker process has restarted my website automatically?

Tags: asp.net, iis, tracking

I want to know if I can track this, because if this happens frequently I want to know root cause of it. Is there any time stamp logging available for restarting of my site in IIS, How can I track this programmatically?

Thanks to all.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933.aspx

Comment: Query the Event Log with WMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could log reason for application restart in Global.asax Application_End :

```
protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpRuntime runtime = (HttpRuntime)typeof(System.Web.HttpRuntime).InvokeMember("_theRuntime", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.GetField, null, null, null);

  string shutDownMessage = "";

  if (runtime != null)
  {
    shutDownMessage = Environment.NewLine + "Shutdown: " +
                      (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownMessage", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null) + 
                      Environment.NewLine + "Stack: " + Environment.NewLine +
                      (string)runtime.GetType().InvokeMember("_shutDownStack", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetField, null, runtime, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, this really seems to tell us what we are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

on Global.asax the

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and the

```
void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

are called when the application starts and ends. You can use them to log it. Now to know why your pool is restarting you can simple check the settings of your pool, there are many reasons that you may have setup, maybe you have set a time limit, maybe a memory limit, maybe other setup... you can check them and change them.

Comment: I already know about this events and we are using it. thanks.